# Is vuejs app.js import path can be dynamic or in if else condition?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

App.js

Original

```
import x from 'project/a'
```

can it be

```
var project = 'a'

if(project == 'a')
{
   import x from 'project/a'
}
else
{
   import x from 'project/b'
}
```

or could it use

```
var project = 'a'
var filepath = '';

if(project == 'a')
{
   filepath = 'project/a';
}
else
{
   filepath = 'project/b';
}

import x from filepath
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

## import both and do the conditional

Imagine one file with codes of projectA and projectB and conditional.

```
import initProjectA
import initProjectB

if (condition) {
  initProjectA()
} else {
  initProjectB()
}
```

this will be compiled down into something like:

```
function initProjectA() {
}

function initProjectB() {
}

if (condition) {
  //
}
```

## dynamic imports:

This will produce 3 separate files: projectA, projectB, conditional.

```
import(module).then(importedModule => {
  importedModule.default() // assuming you did `export default`
})
```

conditional file will only load either one of them then execute it.

- check if it should download projectA or projectB
- once file is downloaded, execute it

You might have to change some configurations to be able to do dynamic imports. You can search for the topic "webpack dynamic imports" on Google.

Comment: the first one will import both of it or import when in if else only?, the second one module is file path?

Comment: @Desmondmeng first one imports both code but will only execute one of them depending on conditional (projectA+projectB+conditional in one file). second one imports only one of them but 3 files will be generated (project A - project B - conditional).

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below:

```
var project = 'a'

let x;

if(project == 'a')
{
   x = require('project/a').default;
}
else
{
   x = require('project/b').default;
}
```

Assuming you are using export default in files being imported